# Regarding the SIGBUS issue of Camera2 API in Android OS 14

Tags: android-camera2, android-14, sigbus

I'm having issues with Camera2API's SIGBUS in debug mode on Android OS 14.
Has anyone experienced the same problem or knows how to resolve it?
I did the following to check the event:

1. This occurs when running an app that uses Camera2 and Native code in debug mode. (Or change the debug type to (Java + Native))

https://developer.android.com/studio/debug?hl=en#debug-types

2. This issue occurs in debug mode on Pixel 7a and Pixel Tablet with Android OS14.
   SIGBUS did not occur on the Galaxy S9, a slightly older model equipped with Android OS 10.
3. The development environment is Android Studio HedgeHog Gentoo Linux.
   (I have two PCs, and the same problem occurs even if I switch between development machines.)
4. I thought the problem might be with the preview View object, so I also tried TextureView and SurfaceView, but the results were the same.
5. I don't think this problem occurred on Android OS 13.
6. I tested it with Camera2 API using the simplest possible code and the result was the same. (A similar phenomenon occurs in the sample code.)

Below is the trace shown when debugging.

SIGBUS (signal SIGBUS: illegal address)

```
art::(anonymous namespace)::ScopedCheck::CheckMethodAndSig(art::ScopedObjectAccess&, _jobject*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, art::Primitive::Type, art::InvokeType) (.__uniq.99033978352804627313491551960229047428) 0x0000006d523dd3e0
art::(anonymous namespace)::CheckJNI::CallMethodV(char const*, _JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list, art::Primitive::Type, art::InvokeType) (.__uniq.99033978352804627313491551960229047428) 0x0000006d523dc0a8
art::(anonymous namespace)::CheckJNI::CallBooleanMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list) (.__uniq.99033978352804627313491551960229047428.llvm.9379289081322328196) 0x0000006d5254d5f4
_JNIEnv::CallBooleanMethod(_jobject*, _jmethodID*, ...) 0x0000006fea369adc
JavaBBinder::onTransact(unsigned int, const android::Parcel &, android::Parcel *, unsigned int) 0x0000006fea420d48
android::BBinder::transact(unsigned int, const android::Parcel &, android::Parcel *, unsigned int) 0x000000700690108c
android::IPCThreadState::executeCommand(int) 0x00000070068ffd38
android::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool) 0x000000700691edf8
android::PoolThread::threadLoop() 0x000000700691eb8c
android::Thread::_threadLoop(void *) 0x0000006fec592d74
android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void *) 0x0000006fea3721a0
__pthread_start(void *) 0x0000006ff7b54cd0
__start_thread 0x0000006ff7ae8b04
```

Since I want to process camera input data with OpenGL, I would like to use Camera2 if possible.

If anyone knows, it would be helpful if you could share the information.

thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem, I was able to debug my kotlin code by turning off the  Native debugging in the Run/Debug configurations and setting it to "java only".

I am not having the same problem on other android devices (Samsung tablet, android 12)

It's pretty annoying, I have a lot of C++ code in there that needs debugging too.

I have tried many different NDKs and there was no difference.